# NotSerializableException on abstract class with no fields

Tags: java, serialization

Here's my tiny class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public abstract class SerializableCallback extends Callback
implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4544768712188843966L;
    public abstract void handleMessage(Message msg);
}
```

Here's its even tinier parent `Callback`:

```
public abstract class Callback {
    public abstract void handleMessage(Message msg);
}
```

And here's my test:

```
public void testSerialization() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    SerializableCallback c = new SerializableCallback() {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4852385037064234702L;
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            callbackMethod();
        }
    };

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeObject(c); // fails
    out.close();

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(FILE);
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = in.readObject();
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    SerializableCallback d = (SerializableCallback) object;
}

private void callbackMethod() {}
```

The test gives me a `NotSerializableException` on the line indicated by a comment. Here's a couple of things by which it can certainly *not* be caused:

1. Missing Serializable declaration
2. Non-serializable fields: there are no fields at all
3. Invisible non-arg constructor of closest non-serializable parent type

So what *does* cause the exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your class doesn't have a no-arg constructor. It has a constructor which takes one argument which is the `this` of the outer class. If you made testSerialization() `static` it might fix the problem.

But I suspect your immediate real problem is that your nest class has a reference to the outer class and the outer class is not Serializable.

Comment: The three classes are not nested so there is not "outer" class. Please explain why there is a constructor like you mentioned? Anyway making `testSerialization()` `static` did fix the problem.

Comment: When your method is not `static` your nested class becomes an inner class which implicitly has a reference to `OuterClass.this` as field whether you need it or use it or not. Its is called `this$0` on typically. To pass this value (and any other `final` local variables you might use) to the constructor, the "default" constructor has to take additional argument(s)

Comment: BTW: If you create a field called `this$0` it will create a field called `this$0$` or `this$0$$` etc. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just to further address your comment on Peter's answer (too long for a comment), the anonymous `SerializableCallback` class in your test method **is technically an inner class**.

- When declared in a non-static method, anonymous classes are essentially non-static inner classes.
- When declared in a static method, anonymous classes are essentially static inner classes.

This is why switching to `static` worked. Since it made the anonymous class you created a static class, it no longer held an implicit reference to your test class and so it was serializable.

Remember that anonymous and inner classes declared at a non-static level always hold a reference to the enclosing class. If it didn't, you wouldn't have been able to call `callbackMethod()` in your anonymous class since the anonymous class doesn't declare it.

When `ObjectOutputStream` tried to serialize your anonymous `SerializableCallback`, it tried to serialize both the callback *and* the test class since the `SerializableCallback` held a reference to it. It was like trying to serialize this class:

```
// Declared in its own file
public class MySerializableCallback extends SerializableCallback {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4852385037064234702L;

    // Equiv to Callback.this in an inner class
    private final CallbackTest test;

    public MySerializableCallback(CallbackTest test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        test.callbackMethod();
    }
}
```

If you tried to serialize this class, it's obvious it would fail because the `CallbackTest` probably isn't serializable.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and thoroughness!

Answer (score 1):

Check for these cases

Under these conditions the Serialization fails:

- Removing of Instance Variable.
- Changing the type of the Instance Variable.
- Changing the Instance Variable from non-transient to transient.
- Changing the Instance Variable from non-static to static.
- Moving the class up and down the hierarchy.

Comment: Kumar, you should know better than to highlight random words like "Removing" with the code-formatting: "Removing" is not code.